# Dragons stuck in Breeding Cave in Dragonvale?

Tags: dragonvale

My kids are playing Dragonvale on their iPod touches, and they have dragons stuck in their breeding cave and they won't come out:

- They've got the most recent update from the app store
- They've waited for over 4 days, and there's no indicator of the breeding completing.

We've tried the following with no luck:

- Reinstalled the app
- Logged in and out of game center
- Tried it on another iPod touch

Any suggestions on how to fix this? They have 2 breeding caves, if it matters, and both are stuck.

Comment: Just to clarify, there are no eggs waiting to hatch in the nursery are there?

Comment: thanks... good point... there aren't any there, so there's room in the nursery!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[According to the developers](http://www.backflipstudios.com/support/faq/), this is a known bug with the game.  Their solution is to contact their support via e-mail (support@backflipstudios.com) and include your Game Center name.

> **Why are my dragons stuck in the breeding cave with no incubation button or progress bar?**
>
> We are sorry; this is a known bug we are working to fix.  In the meantime, please send an  email to support@backflipstudios.com and include your Game Center nickname.  We’ll fix the issue right away!

Comment: I tried this, and it worked. They responded, and fixed my cave. Thanks for the help!